# How to remove ui-state-active class while click on the dates from datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When i click on the particular dates in the jQuery-ui datepicker then the ui-state-active class added on that date. I want to remove that class on click of that date or onSelect event of the date.

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:////code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

You  can remove class on [beforeShowDay()](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).In beforeShowDay() you can remove `ui-state-active` class easily using `setTimeout function`.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").find(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
        },100);
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            setTimeout(function () {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").find(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
            },100);
              return [true, '', ''];
            }
        });
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading JQueryUI from their website (then you can choose which plugins you want to get a smaller file) and edit the single line of code which adds the class to selected days. Search for "datepicker" then in that section look for "ui-state-active".

Or an alternative and perfectly good solution is to just change your CSS for .ui-state-active in the datepicker.

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #454545;
}
```